# How can I make this take the text they put in the input box and then put it into local storage

Tags: javascript, html

i don't understand why it doesn't send what they put in the input box to local storage

```html
<body>
<input id="name">
<button onclick="bob()">
save
</button>
</body>

<script>


const person = document.getElementByid("name");

window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(person));
</script>
```

Comment: Use `person.value` to get what they entered.

Comment: where do I put that?

Comment: Instead of `JSON.stringify(person)` of course. Do you understand what `.value` is?

Comment: kinda i thought it would just be JSON.stringify(person.value) but that didn't work

Comment: Since `person.value` is already a string, there's no need to stringify it.

Comment: Is that code inside the `bob()` function? If you run it at top-level, it runs when the page loads, not when the user clicks.

Comment: so it would be window.localStorage.setItem('user', person.value); and i already put all of the js into a function so the onclick works

Comment: Yes, but fix the typo

Comment: that doesn't seem to work function bob(){
const person = document.getElementByid("name");

window.localStorage.setItem('user', person.value);} thats my code

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: replace `JSON.stringify(person)` with `person.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `value` property to get what the user entered.

```
function bob() {
    const person = document.getElementById("name");
    window.localStorage.setItem('user', person.value);
}
```